# What is command to find detailed information about Kubernetes master(s) using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Let say I want to find the kubelet and apiserver version of my k8s master(s), what's the best way to do it?

I am aware of the following commands:

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

which only shows the endpoints.

```
kubectl get nodes; kubectl describe node <node>;
```

which shows very detail information but only the nodes and not master.

There's also

```
kubectl version
```

but that only shows the kubectl version and not the kubelet or apiserver version.

What other commands can I use to identify the properties of my cluster?

Comment: Found another one called `kubectl get cs/componentstatuses`, which lists controller-manager and scheduler but it does not show version and `kubectl describe cs` is not implemented.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

`kubectl version` also shows the apiserver version. For example, this is the output when I run it:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

The second line ("Server Version") contains the apiserver version. There isn't a way to get the master's kubelet version if it isn't registered as one of the nodes (which it isn't if it isn't showing up in `kubectl get nodes`), but in most deployments it'll be the same version as the apiserver.

Comment: You can also add `-o yaml` to most commands to get more details, e.g. `kubectl get nodes -o yaml` will give you the nodes' kubelet versions.

Answer (score 42):

`kubectl version --short` will give you a short and sweet ***version*** of your k8-cluster

```
aathith@k8-master:~# kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.18.1
Server Version: v1.18.1
```

**edit 1:**
In terminal 1

```
aathith@k8-master:~# kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

In terminal 2

```
aathith@k8-master:~# curl http://localhost:8001/version -k
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "18",
  "gitVersion": "v1.18.1",
  "gitCommit": "e0fccafd69541e3750d460ba0f9743b90336f24f",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2020-04-16T11:35:47Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.13.9",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes i agree with above answers that most of the time kubectl version --short will be the same as kubelet's and apiserver version.

But according to k8s documentation : **kubectl is supported within one minor version (older or newer) of kube-apiserver** so there is a possibility that kubectl version can be different.

[Kubenetes doc screenshot]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSnlC.png

If you are able to see the nodes using `kubectl get nodes` then best way to get kubelet version by performing below commands

```
kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -i 'kubelet'
kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -i 'apiserver'
```

[kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -i 'apiserver' output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCQd2.png)

[kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -i 'kubelet' output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN75F.png)

you can remove grep and search for other attributes also in yaml

Comment: `kubectl version` will return a `Server version` along with the `Client version`. This `Server version` *is* the kube-api server version. Although your solution of getting and grepping nodes does work, `kubectl version` (with or without the `--short` flag) will give an accurate kube-api server version, and is much lighter and easier to read than getting and grepping all the nodes like your solution.