# How to fix kubectl Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I was install kubectl by the official instruction, but when i've try `kubectl apply -f` i've get " `Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource` " error.

The Internet says that it's because the Client and Server Version of kubectl is different.

I'll check the verision of kubectl:

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.2", GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:30:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

`Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4", GitCommit:"d6f433224538d4f9ca2f7ae19b252e6fcb66a3ae", GitTreeState:"dirty", BuildDate:"2017-06-22T04:31:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

If it is official install, why version so different? And is it really problem of this error?

I also have docker, docker-compose and minikube.

OS Linux Mint

Comment: what is the official doc? can you provide a link?

Comment: just downgrade your kubectl then

Comment: That’s an ancient version of Kubernetes.  If you’re trying to deploy something like an `apps/v1` Deployment, you’ll get that error.  A [mcve] showing what commands and YAML artifacts actually produce the error would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting Community Wiki as root cause was mentioned by @David Maze

As was pointed in the comments, your versions are very different. 
[Kubernetes 1.7](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/07/kubernetes-1.7) was realesed ~ **July 2017**, when [Kubernetes 1.17](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/) was released in **Jan 2020** (almost 2,5 year difference). Another thing is version of `Docker` and `Minikube` must support `kubernetes` version.

As Example, if you would like to run Kubernetes 1.6.3 on latest `Minikube` version, error occurs.

```
minikube v1.7.3 on Ubuntu 16.04
✨  Using the none driver based on user configuration
⚠️  Specified Kubernetes version 1.6.4 is less than the oldest supported version: v1.11.10
  Sorry, Kubernetes 1.6.4 is not supported by this release of minikube
```

Also, there was huge change in `apiVersions` between version 1.15 and 1.16. More details can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/).

In [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230452/what-is-command-to-find-detailed-information-about-kubernetes-masters-using-ku) was explained what is shown in `kubectl version`.

> The second line ("Server Version") contains the apiserver version.

As for example `Network Policy API` was introduced in Kubernetes 1.7, so if you would like to use it in 1.6, you will get error as API cannot recognize it.

I've reproduced your issue.

```
minikube:~$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.3", GitCommit:"06ad960bfd03b39c8310aaf92d1e7c12ce618213", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-11T18:14:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.3", GitCommit:"0480917b552be33e2dba47386e51decb1a211df6", GitTreeState:"dirty", BuildDate:"2017-05-12T10:50:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
minikube:~$ kubectl get pods
Error from server (NotAcceptable): the server was unable to respond with a content type that the client supports (get pods)
minikube:~$ kubectl get nodes
Error from server (NotAcceptable): the server was unable to respond with a content type that the client supports (get nodes)
minikube:~$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx
WARNING: New generator "deployment/apps.v1" specified, but it isn't available. Falling back to "deployment/apps.v1beta1".
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
error: no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1"
```

As I mentioned before, `Network Policy` was introduced in 1.7. When you will try apply [this config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource) from Official Kubernetes docs, it will show the same error you have.

```
minikube:~$ kubectl apply -f network.yaml 
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource.
```

Most recommended way is to install newest versions of docker, kubernetes and minikube (security and newest features) based on [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) and [Kubernetes kubectl docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) and [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/linux/).

Another option is to downgrade all components.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade your kubectl version. And please mention the official doc you followed to install initially.

`sudo apt-get install -qy kubectl=1.16.3-00`

On second note I think David is right. Maybe you have mismatch in api in your manifest and the k8s version.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` and get "Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource", the reason is most probably the deprecated API used in the deployment.yaml.

API version you use in the deployment.yaml file could be deprecated for your Kubernetes version. Please check the official guide to find the new version of the API to use: [Deprecated API Migration Guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/).